# pgAdmin III shows duplicate connection to same server

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

My `pgAdmin` suddenly shows two connections to the very same server (localhost).

[image: PgAdmin III connections]

I can't remember what particular actions I did the last time before opening the software today.

Both servers contain the same databases and login roles.

**Q:**

- Why does this happen?
- Is it safe to just delete / drop either one?

Windows Services shows only one PostgreSQL Server service running:

[image: Windows Services]

---

pgAdmin III version is: `1.22.2 (May 9 2017,rev:REL-1_22_1)`

PostgreSQL version is: `9.5.7`

OS version is: `Windows 10 Pro 1803 build 17134.48`

Don't know what additional info I should provide, so please feel free to ask.

Comment: Do you install PostgreSQL Server two times?

Comment: @MabuKloesen no, as you can see from the the picture I just added, there is only one pg service running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pgAdmin is just a `client` to view your `postgresql server` details. You can add as many servers as you want in pgAdmin (because they are not server instances it is just UI interface to access data easily, they call it server because you are connecting to server through it) but ultimately they would be connected to only one server.

> Why does this happen?

It might have happened that you have created a duplicate connection to it as 
   you can't remember what particular actions you did the last time before 
   opening the software today.

> Is it safe to just delete / drop either one?

Feel free to delete it from `pgAdmin` as it will just be that interface is 
   deleted, your data is perfectly safe.

Hope this helps !